# JavaScript: My Dragged Image Disappears When Dropped Onto a TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched around SO but have not found other posts that talk about the same specific issue that I'm dealing with. I've found several posts that talk about images disappearing when dropping them on top of other images, but I haven't found one that talks about images disappearing when dropping them onto empty textareas.

Can anyone help me understand why my images are disappearing?

(note: my fiddle doesn't work the way that I have it working on my desktop; not sure what I'm missing; at the moment, when user drags image onto textarea, the url shows up; also, my add new cell button is not working; i added the scripts that I'm using to the "external resources" section)

`Here is my fiddle:`https://jsfiddle.net/m52crpxa/5/

Comment: I think ( but not sure) dataTransfer is for drag a file from windows to browser? For example in select file for upload.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

Comment: Where is text area in linked page?

Comment: I provided that link to show you that w3schools uses dataTransfer to drag an image onto one of their divs. They don't use textarea, instead they use a div. However, I've seen instances of other users here on SO who used textarea as their drop zone. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I've decided to use divs instead of textareas as my "drop zone". The images will drag and successfully drop, but now the issue is that the image that is dropped, is huge. In the fiddle, the image that displays is actually resized to 120px for height and width; once dropped, however, it retains it's original size (I got the images from google images)

Comment: I have an easy way to do this without dataTransfer, Do you wand that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course when you drag image to taxe area it will disappear, and in text area you will have the url of the dragged image (in some browsers image will open in new tab).

If you want the image show in the dragged place put your taxtarea with transparent background in div. and set the text area:

```css
#div1{width: 150px; height:150px; position:relative; border:1px solid;}

textarea{
  position:absolut;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}

#div1 img{width: 100%;height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1"><img /> <textarea></textarea></div>
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/087039a00851e75ff483470e3aba89c9?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" />
    
<script>
  $('textarea').on("drop", function ()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $($this).prev().attr('src', $this.val());
            $this.parent().css('border', '1px solid');
        }, 200);
    });
  $("textarea").bind("dragover", function ()
    {        
        $(this).parent().css('border', '2px dashed red');        
    });

    $('textarea').bind('dragleave', function ()
    {        
        $(this).parent().css('border', '1px solid');
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Please see this answer, In this way you have not the image size problem.

Comment: Thank you, Farzin, for your time and effortts. I believe this answers the question (sort of), so I'll mark it as correct; however, as I said above, I decided to change the textarea to div instead. Now, when i drop the images, they don't disappear, but there is an issue with the image size. (the reason I'm not going to use your code is because I don't understand what's going on. the example code that w3schools uses is much more understandable for me, so i'm using theirs; i just wish i could understand why my images aren't retaining the resized dimensions once it's dropped onto the divs)

Comment: As i said in this way you do not have the image size problem, and it is very easy, a textarea masked an image, but it is not visible `opcity: 0` . you drag the image to textarea and set the text of textarea to image src(by jquery). btw thanks for accept.